⨯ Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node
I am trying to deploy my create-t3 application to Vercel, the build is successful but when I go to the website the server has a 500 internal server error and the logs throw an error like this:
⨯ Error: No native build was found for platform=linux arch=x64 runtime=node abi=115 uv=1 libc=glibc node=20.15.1
    loaded from: /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/argon2@0.40.1/node_modules/argon2

    at load.resolve.load.path (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/node-gyp-build@4.8.1/node_modules/node-gyp-build/node-gyp-build.js:60:9)
    at load (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/node-gyp-build@4.8.1/node_modules/node-gyp-build/node-gyp-build.js:22:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/argon2@0.40.1/node_modules/argon2/argon2.cjs:7:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at /opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11506
    at Function.Zt (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11879)
    at Y.e.<computed>.Z._load (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11476) {
  page: '/'
}

any solution?
I've tried to redeploy but i hadn't any solution. I'm trying to migrate my project to create-t3-turbo. any solution?
